# No images in GitHub Pages RSS feed

Tags: rss, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I recently set up a blog with Jekyll / GitHub Pages and it automatically provides an RSS feed.
Embedding images in the blog itself works perfectly fine, using:

```
{{ site.baseurl }}/...
```

but in the RSS feed, they are not displayed.
I also noticed that this website: https://validator.w3.org/feed/ throws quite some errors, always saying that `description should not contain relative URL references: /blog/assets/images/IMG_8196.jpg`.

It would be great if you had an idea on how to solve this, because absolute URLs aren't too great especially when it comes to testing on own server / localhost.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: RSS feed is one of the places where you MUST use absolutes urls.

Comment: @DavidJacquel so there’s absolutely no elegant solution where e.g. Jekyll “generates” the absolute URLs? (Like {{ site.baseurl }} )

Answer (score 0):

In *_config.yml*, set `url` and `baseurl`, if needed.

Any link or resource in your *feed.xml* **must** be pointing to an absolute url. This file is consumed my tools that only knows where to find things with absolute urls.

```
{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/myPath/myFile.html
```

This can also be done with the new `absolute_url` filter

```
{{ "myPath/myFile.html" | absolute_url }}
```

And this is true for links, images, css, js, and so on.

Comment: So these both work even if it's offline?
And what's the "logic" of the second one? 
I guess the first one appends baseurl to url right?

Comment: For more information, you can read [jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).

Comment: Okay I've understood the syntax now, but this means it won't work until the file is on the server right?  
There's no way to have it "detect" that it's not offline anymore and to use the absolute URL.